# How can I see the cartesian plane on the interface builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, coordinates, cartesian

Is there a way to see the cartesian plane on the Interface Builder? I don't know how to figure out the exact coordinates to draw, for example a NSImage, can you guys teach me how to locate myself on with/without a graphical environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to show a grid that represents the coordinate space. You'll need to just place and size a view. You can either delete it after you've written down its frame or keep that view and use it (for example, instead of drawing an NSImage, you might place and use an NSImageView).

Comment: Well, I think it would be really hard to use the NSImageView because, my intention is to create a view that will draw an image object, but I need options like fullscreen mode, converting coordinates tasks and a lot others that already exists on the NSView. I also need to draw multiple images at a view, is that possible? Thanks for the help.

Comment: NSImageView is a subclass of NSView, so it inherits all of NSView's goodness. (Otherwise you wouldn't be able to add an image view as a subview!) You cannot draw multiple images with a single image view. At any rate, it doesn't matter whether you use an NSImageView or a custom view: You must place and size a view and then either use that or copy its frame into your code.